# How does the US Census Bureau simplify its Cartographic Boundary Shapefiles?

Tags: united-states, census, simplify

The [US Census Cartographic Boundary Shapefiles](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-cart-boundary.html) are available in 1:500,000 and 1:5,000,000 and 1:20,000,000 resolutions.

The boundaries are [well-aligned](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_description.html) and the data otherwise seemingly clean.

How are these made? Is there an algorithm that's used followed by manual clean-up, or some other process?

Comment: Have you searched their website?  Have you asked them?

Comment: I've looked online. But, in the immortal words of Boromir, "One does not simply search the Census Bureau's website." I've also contacted them: a process of uncertain duration which will produce private knowledge with little public benefit unless it's posted somewhere.

Comment: To wax philosophical, contacting them is a selfish action: given the Bureau's [budget difficulties](https://www.washingtonpost.com/local/social-issues/us-census-director-resigns-amid-turmoil-over-funding-of-2020-count/2017/05/09/8f8657c6-34ea-11e7-b412-62beef8121f7_story.html) and the importance of an accurate Census in determining so many aspects of life in the US, I'd have preferred to exhaust other means of answering this before using their resources.

Comment: If its open data, then maybe the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange is another place that you could research/ask.  https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=Cartographic+Boundary+Shapefiles

Comment: @PolyGeo: Thanks! I'll be sure to give that a try. I'll wait a bit, though, to avoid cross-posting. :-)